# How to set JavaFX default skin

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I noticed that when I run JavaFX application on JVM 7 and JVM 8 I get different default skins. How I can set the default skin to be same on every JVM?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the default skin:

```
@Override 
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    ....
    setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN);
    ....
}
```

http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/

Comment: Isn't that a JavaFX 8 method? Will that run on JRE 7?

Comment: @OttPrime No it won't run on 7, use `System.setProperty( "javafx.userAgentStylesheetUrl", "CASPIAN" );`

Comment: The above will work when launching the application as a jar, but for some reason won't work when launching it using Java Web Start, any idea why? I've been struggling with this for a while now, I can't seem to find a reason for it.

Answer (score 6):

The default stylesheet for JavaFX 2 is caspian.css. You can find it in jfxrt.jar under com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.caspian. This changed with JavaFX 8 and I believe the default stylesheet is named [modena.css](http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/). In order to get a common stylesheet, you will have to either define your own or copy one of the defaults into your project.

Answer (score 2):

You can also run with -Djavafx.userAgentStylesheetUrl=caspian on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own skin by adding a style sheet.

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(
    getClass().getResource("my-skin.css").toExternalForm());
```

Unfortunately there is no default style sheet. Maybe browsing in jfxrt.jar might yield something.

Comment: Are there any other skins build into JavaFX which I can use?

Comment: Not that I know, but I am not that experienced with JavaFX at all.

Comment: @OttPrime Make it into an answer; I have sufficient points already.