# How to set default javafx themes

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

In my project, I have use **jdk8** in javafx project theme will appear in [image]

After that i will change **jdk8u25**

[image]

how to resolve that problems. I am also ref for this

1. [How to set JavaFX default skin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297777/how-to-set-javafx-default-skin)
2. http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/

Comment: What is the output of `java -version` and `javac -version` in termianl ?My java version is `1.8.0_25` and everything works fine

Comment: 1.8.0_25 in my java version......