# Use modena.css with JavaFX2 and Java 7

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, java-7

I am developing a JavaFX application. Unfortunately, I am restricted to Java 7, thus also restricted to JavaFX2. However, I would like to include the default theme from JavaFX 8 `Modena`. Hence, I downloaded the modena.css and put it into my `src/main/resources/` folder. Now I would like to set this css as my default theming.

Seeing [How to set JavaFX default skin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297777/how-to-set-javafx-default-skin) I tried setting

```
System.setProperty( "javafx.userAgentStylesheetUrl","src/main/resources/modena.css")
```

but the styling wasn't any different.

How can I set another default css file other than caspian using Java 7 and JavaFx 2?

Answer (score 0):

`src` part of the path looks wrong. You need to provide the path which is valid **at runtime**, check your build or target folder to see what is it.

Most probably right path is `main/resources/modena.css`

You can also write next in your code to see if path is correct:

```
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("main/resources/modena.css"));
```

if it's null — your path is wrong.